# Swagger Error (Unknown query parameter 'scope'), after Google OAuth redirection

Tags: swagger

Getting this error when redirecting from google after OAuth authentication, Google OAuth working fine without swagger, but when implementing swagger pop's up this error, please help Thanks.

//Browser Response

```
// http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/google/redirect?code=4%2F0AY0e-g5NJ_iE3ghhL2ZvcDXs_hsEbqUGhgjgBvYj8CT2CAw9yJDPuemT7Mx7EsDSyiSCQ&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+openid&authuser=0&prompt=consent#
```

//Swagger.yml file

```
/auth/google/redirect:
get:
  parameters:
    - in: query
      name: code
      schema:
        type: string
      required: true
      allowReserved: true

  tags:
    - Google login
  description: Redirect from google with user data
  responses:
    200:
      description: Returns from google with user data
      content: {}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1qW9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have these two routes in your API where the bold parameters are required.

GET - /redirect?code={type}
GET - /redirect?code={from}&scope={to}
How would you describe this in Swagger 3.0?

Currently, you can "hack" it by defining the route like the following.

```
/redirect:
get:
  parameters:
    - in: query
      name: code
      schema:
        type: string
      required: true
      allowReserved: true
    - in: query
      name: scope
      schema:
        type: string
      required: true
      allowReserved: true
```